# can we use AJAX with XHTML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xhtml

Can we use AJAX for updating a XHTML page?
To connect the html page, we used to write:

```
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("target").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
```

However, we can't change `innerHTML` to `innerXHTML`, because AJAX doesn't accept it.

Comment: XHTML is `still` HTML; it just imposes an extra set of rules around how the HTML should be presented and written. innerHTML [or jQuery's html()] is still applicable regardless of whether you've written HTML or XHTML. I put `still` in quotes as you may wish to read more about the subject here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML

Comment: They are the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can update XHTML pages using ajax. You still use `innerHTML` (or the DOM methods). The description of [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-innerhtml) in the HTML5 spec describes how XML vs. HTML should be treated.

Re the various DOM methods, some reading/reference material:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) (which applies to XHTML documents as well)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

Comment: NEVER EVER use innerHTML, it's a proprietary Microsoft JScript method that is not compatible with the DOM.

Comment: @John: `innerHTML` is supported across all major (and probably all minor) browsers, compatible with the DOM, and included in the [latest spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-innerhtml). Like Ajax and the ability to have multiple event handlers for the same event on the same DOM element, it **was** originally a Microsoft innovation. (There was a time when Microsoft were the innovators in web browsers. It was a long time ago, and far too short-lived, but prolific.) That doesn't make it evil, and it doesn't mean you shouldn't use it. I'm sure 80%+ of the top 1M sites do.

Comment: Not going to argue with you, it's not reliable, it's NOT a standard (even if it's strong armed in regardless of the standards bodies as they are both dominated by corporations) and it's not compatible with application level programming. Lazy code will produce subpar results, period.

Comment: @John: Sorry, I'm immune to hyperbole. :-) If you want to actually *back up* what you've said, great, love to hear it. Anything else is just noise -- misleading noise, at that.

Comment: Considering that innerHTML is a proprietary Microsoft JScript method the weight is on you to prove the lazy programmer with poor coding practices approach is acceptable. It's not even in any of the specs you referenced. Furthermore my site has been served as application/xhtml+xml for years.

Comment: @John: **Sigh** Yes, it is, see [§2.2.2 of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#dependencies) (my fourth bullet), which includes [the DOM Parsing and Serialization spec](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html) as a normative inclusion. And again, `innerHTML` has been supported by all major and minor browsers for at least a decade. A browser that didn't implement it would be nearly useless. You can keep calling it proprietary all you want. Doesn't change reality.

Comment: Correct, all browser supporting an unreliable proprietary Microsoft JScript method is still an unreliable proprietary Microsoft JScript method which still does not correctly work with the DOM. I exchange with editors often about dozens of bugs in the implementations and specs. If you insist on pushing unreliable code on people I will insist on warning them.

Comment: @John: (`innerHTML` is a *property*, not a method.) Do you think you could use the word "proprietary" again? I don't think you got enough of them in that last comment. You seem to think repeating your claims (I can't call them an argument) in some way strengthens them. It doesn't. I'm done, there's no point to this exchange.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was "of course!". As T.J. Crowder points out, standards-compliant browsers which [follow the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-innerhtml) should have no problem.

However, there does seem to be talk of some issues using innerHTML and maintaining well-formed XHTML markup in older versions of IE.

**Keep in mind that this is old information. It may no longer be a problem.**

http://www.stainlessvision.com/jquery-html-vs-innerxhtml (which uses innerHTML)
http://www.stevetucker.co.uk/page-innerxhtml.php

My experience has been to the contrary, i.e. using `innerHTML` to insert markup is *not* a problem.

The AJAX piece is really irrelevant here; the question is whether or not `innerHTML` can be trusted to preserve the integrity of the markup being inserted into the document.

Answer (score 0):

My site linked in my profile is served entirely as XHTML served as actual XHTML, application/xhtml+xml. Clicking on 'Site Options' at the top-right will in example load content via AJAX.

- Code is not text, do not use responseText, use responseXML.
- Never EVER use innerHTML, it's a proprietary Microsoft JScript method that is not compatible with the DOM. Using it adds huge swathes of ambiguity to your code, JavaScript may see elements you've loaded via AJAX but probably won't.
- Use importNode as I have, these are two different document owners and you have to use importNode to load content from different documents.